# Use wxPython.FileDialog to save file

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am using `wx.FileDialog` to pop a directory select dialog for the user to choose the save path. The file type I'd like to save is `.csv` files.

Here is the code:

```
fdlg = wx.FileDialog(self.panel_settings, "Input setting file path", "", "", "CSV files(*.csv)|*.*", wx.FD_SAVE)

if fdlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    self.save_path = fdlg.GetPath() + ".csv"

with open(self.save_path, "wb") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter = ',')
```

When a dialog pops up, I simply type in `test` as the file name. As I click `OK` button, it directly save an empty `test.csv` file.

However, what I want to do is just keep the input path and file name, then write the content myself.

So, may I know how to work around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wx.FileDialog does not create the file, it returns the path.  ***You*** are creating the file with this code:

```
with open(self.save_path, "wb") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter = ',')
```